# HTTP PUT request in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to perform a PUT request using the id of the item (/UpdateTodo/:id) in expressjs but according to my code, what I am actually doing is just adding a new set of json which can have the same id.

Here are the codes for a better understanding:

```
app.put('/UpdateTodo/:id', function (req, res) {

  var date = new Date();
  var _id = 0;

  if (todoList.length > 0) {
    _id = todoList[todoList.length - 1].id + 1;
  }

  var dt = date.toLocaleString();

  req.params.id = Number(req.params.id);

  var todoitem = { id: req.params.id, item: req.body.item, createdTime: dt, completedTime: "", status: "new" };

  todoList.push(todoitem);
  res.send(todoitem);
});
```

My app.post works as expected:

```
app.post('/InsertTodo', function (req, res) {

  var date = new Date();
  var _id = 0;

  if (todoList.length > 0) {
    _id = todoList[todoList.length - 1].id + 1;
  }

  var dt = date.toLocaleString();

  var todoitem = { id: _id, item: req.body.item, createdTime: dt, completedTime: "", status: "new" };

  todoList.push(todoitem);
  res.send(todoitem);
});
```

[image: postman put result]

All in all, my question is, how do I update the item based on the id instead of adding another item which may have the same id?

Comment: You need to find the previous item with the same `id` and remove it from the array before adding the new one. Just curious, what is the poiint of the `_id` variable in the first snippet? From what I can tell, you're not using it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your PUT request should try and find an existing item with the same ID before updating it. If one doesn't exist, it should create one.

For example:

```
const item = todoList.find(item => item.id === req.params.id);
if (item) { ... }
```

Instead of using an array to store your items (`todoList`) you could look into using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Doing `Map.get()` and `Map.set()` might make this an interesting learning experience.

One other word of advice, your routes don't need to be worded differently. The HTTP method (PUT, POST, etc) will make them unique, so instead of

- `app.put('/UpdateTodo`
- `app.post('/InsertTodo`

Just do

- `app.put('/todo, function(req, res) { ... });`
- `app.post('/todo, function(req, res) { ... });`

Comment: Hi, any example of what I should include in the if statement? Been testing different things but it still shows that I've added a new item with the same ID instead of updating the said ID.

Comment: Try check for the id's existence with '==' instead of '==='